# How do you calculate the average of a all entries in a field from a specific collection in Mongo using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Given the following data:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("51659dc99d62eedc1a000001"),
  type: "image_search",
  branch: "qa_media_discovery_feelobot",
  time_elapsed: 19000,
  test: "1365613930 All Media",
  search_term: null,
  env: "delta",
  date: ISODate("2013-04-10T17:13:45.751Z")
}
```

I would like to run a command like:

```
avg_image_search_time = @coll.find("type" => "image_search").avg(:time_elapsed)
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the documentation on this is kind of difficult to follow.

```
avg_image_search_time = @coll.aggregate([ {"$group" => {"_id"=>"$type", "avg"=> {"$avg"=>"$time_elapsed"}}}, {"$match" => {"_id"=>"image_search"}} ]).first['avg']
```

To break this down:

We are grouping the matches by the `type` field, and returning the `$avg` time_elapsed for each type. We name the resulting average `avg`. Then, of those groups, filter out only the ones where the group _id matches `image_search`. Finally, since aggregate always returns an array, get the first result (there should only be one), and grab the `avg` field that we named.

Comment: Thanks I tested it and it worked like a charm I have been trying to do this for 3 days with no success. For a newb to mongo it was really daunting trying to find help in the docs. You the man!

Answer (score 1):

Use the mongodb aggregation framework  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/

Comment: This is not a very useful answer since I specifically mentioned help doing this in ruby but thanks anyway.